# drawing a shape in drawRect

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have the following code:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGFloat commentHeight = 0;


        CGSize commentSize = [self.highlightItem_.comment sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:kProximaNova size:18] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(rect.size.width, CGFLOAT_MAX) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
        commentHeight = commentSize.height + 50;

        CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 68/255.f, 68/255.f, 68/255.f, 1.0);
        CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 68/255.f, 68/255.f, 68/255.f, 1.0);
        CGContextSetLineJoin(context, kCGLineCapSquare);
        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1.0);

        CGMutablePathRef pathRef = CGPathCreateMutable();

        CGPathMoveToPoint(pathRef, NULL, 0, rect.size.height - commentHeight);
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathRef, NULL, 20, rect.size.height - commentHeight);
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathRef, NULL, 25, rect.size.height - commentHeight - 10);
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathRef, NULL, 30, rect.size.height - commentHeight);
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathRef, NULL, rect.size.width, rect.size.height - commentHeight);
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathRef, NULL, rect.size.width, rect.size.height);
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathRef, NULL, 0, rect.size.height);
        CGPathCloseSubpath(pathRef);

        CGContextAddPath(context, pathRef);
        //CGContextFillPath(context);
        CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFill);


        CGPathRelease(pathRef);
}
```

For some reason it's not drawing the shape I want. In fact it draws nothing. Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Comment: You should definitely call [super drawRect:rect]; at the end of the method.

Comment: Does this view have any subviews?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code above works just fine.

I guess you're drawing out of screen as I see the comment bubble on the very bottom of the iPhone 5 screen when using a full screen view.

Look below for the result when using a small centred view.

[image]

Comment: iPhone 5 native resolution. Blame Apple ;)